# SQL Server Reporting Services report print layout fine but normal layout ko

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, rendering, ssrs-2012

In the normal view layout, my form report is unproperly formatted. When I change to Print layout, it is properly formatted.

I want my view layout to be the same as the print layout.

> Normal layout (or ko layout)

[image]

> Page layout (ok layout)

[image]

I've tweaked the layout properties, with width 7.5in like for an A4 sheet of paper but to no avail

If you have any ideas , they are more than welcomed as I'm losing sanity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a Table/Tablix control to layout the textboxes in each section consistently. If you just use textboxes on a List object, the rendering is harder to control.

Assuming each section is represented by a single dataset record, I would add 7 rows in the table Details section.  The first row would show RAISON, the 2nd would show APE, and so on.  You can merge columns on individual rows if you need that specific layout, but the more you can standardize the column widths the easier it will be to build.

If you really need to continue with floating textboxes, then I would suggest entering exact measurements for Location and Size properties - textboxes must have the same Location / Top measurement to be rendered on the same "row" across the page.

Comment: Hi @mike-honey , 

Many thanks for your answer. You are the only , to have answer , and a correct answer should I say to ,my question.

The bounty is yours and many many thanks, again, to have address my issue.

All the best,
Andy